# regexp for python list

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of git branches in Python.

`['fb_fix', 'master', 'rel.100.0', 'rel.101.0', 'rel.96.0', 'rel.96.2', 'rel.96.2.0', 'rel.97.0']`

I need a regular expression via re module, which will include all the list items where there is prefix `rel.` and any numbers by masks `00.0` or `00.0.0` or `000.0` or `000.0.0`, i.e. exclude other values from the list, in my example this is `'fb_fix'` and `'master'`:

`['rel.100.0', 'rel.101.0', 'rel.96.0', 'rel.96.2', 'rel.96.2.0', 'rel.97.0']`

```
import subprocess

git_branches = subprocess.run("git branch -r", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
branches_str = git_branches.stdout.replace("origin/", "")

branches_list = branches_str.split()
print(branches_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```py
inp = ['fb_fix', 'master', 'rel.100.0', 'rel.101.0', 'rel.96.0', 'rel.96.2', 'rel.96.2.0', 'rel.97.0']
output = [x for x in inp if re.search(r'^rel\.\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}', x)]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['rel.100.0', 'rel.101.0', 'rel.96.0', 'rel.96.2', 'rel.96.2.0',
 'rel.97.0']
```

**Edit**:

Assuming that the value `rel` is in some string variable, then we can try dynamically building the regex pattern here:

```py
prefix = 'rel'
regex = r'^' + prefix + r'\.\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}'
inp = ['fb_fix', 'master', 'rel.100.0', 'rel.101.0', 'rel.96.0', 'rel.96.2', 'rel.96.2.0', 'rel.97.0']
output = [x for x in inp if re.search(regex, x)]
print(output)  # same output as above
```

Comment: Hi Tim.
Thank you for your quick answer. Can I do prefix `rel` like variable?

Comment: Are you saying that you have some variable with the value `'rel'` and you want to build the regex pattern dynamically?

Comment: Absolutely right. I tried to `re.search(r"^\\{}\.\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}".format(prefix), branch)` Perhaps I need to escape characters

Comment: @DenisMozhaev Check the updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks Tim. 
`prefix = "rel"`
`regex = r"^" + prefix + r"\.\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2}"`
`b = [branch for branch in branches_list if re.search(regex, branch)]`

Comment: @DenisMozhaev You should really ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lambda:

```
filtered = filter(lambda k: 'rel' in k, branches_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can make use of the `filter` function plus `re.compile` just like so-

```
import re

git_branches = ['fb_fix', 'master', 'rel.100.0', 'rel.101.0', 'rel.96.0', 'rel.96.2', 'rel.96.2.0', 'rel.97.0']

r = re.compile('^(rel.*)')
my_branches = filter(r.match, git_branches)
print(list(my_branches))
```

the output of the code about is this ->

```
>>> ['rel.100.0', 'rel.101.0', 'rel.96.0', 'rel.96.2', 'rel.96.2.0', 'rel.97.0']
```